# fscrypt - running a script inside encrypted folder on startup

Tags: linux, file, encryption, debian

I am using fscrypt with pam_passphrase on a folder. I want to:

1. Run a script inside the encrypted folder, with the user that owns the folder.
2. Start this script automatically after booting.

Is this possible without logging in with the user users password?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you mean “without entering the user's password”, then I believe this is not possible in principle. In order to read the script, the folder needs to be decrypted which requires the user's password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to do this using the users password, so I ended up using the "raw_key" protector.